# How to rebuild an Image in Yocto with an updated Module

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

first of all, I know that this question has been asked already since every Yocto Beginner stumbles over it sooner or later, but the offered solutions didn't work for me.

I'm building a mlinux Image using Yocto and I added three packages.
Two of them are given by multitech and the other one (lora-gateway-bridge) is from git.
Since the recipe didn't copy the config files, i changed the .init part and tried to rebuild the project.

However the init files which are installed by the image, don't have the changes.

I tried rebuilding the recipe (bitbake lora-gateway-bridge) and afterwards the image (bitbake mlinux-base-image) first.
Then I read the other question here and tried:

```
bitbake lora-gateway-bridge -c clean -f
and
bitbake lora-gateway-bridge -c cleanstate -f
and afterwards
bitbake mlinux-base-image
```

This is the part of the **recipe for the image**, in which the package is installed:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "lora-gateway"
IMAGE_INSTALL += "lora-packet-forwarder"
IMAGE_INSTALL += "lora-gateway-bridge"
```

The source for the recipe itself is: https://github.com/brocaar/lora-gateway-os/tree/master/layers/loraserver/meta-loraserver/recipes-loraserver/lora-gateway-bridge

The **edited recipe for the package** is:

```
DESCRIPTION = "LoRa Gateway Bridge"
HOMEPAGE = "https://www.loraserver.io/"
PRIORITY = "optional"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=5301050fd7cd58850085239d559297be"
SRC_URI = "https://artifacts.loraserver.io/downloads/lora-gateway-bridge/lora-gateway-bridge_${PV}_linux_armv5.tar.gz \
           file://lora-gateway-bridge.toml \
           file://lora-gateway-bridge.init \
"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "e7700cd481eb1c6545ae5b4bf51379cd"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "4ebe707b634087951f6f99a6e1a3ffe65ff1f8bcd43ebf66e83776d3c6f5248d"
PR = "r1"

LORA_GATEWAY_BRIDGE_DIR = "/opt/lora-gateway-bridge"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${LORA_GATEWAY_BRIDGE_DIR}
    install -m 755 lora-gateway-bridge ${D}${LORA_GATEWAY_BRIDGE_DIR}/

    #install -d ${D}/var/config/lora-gateway-bridge
    #install -m 0640 ${WORKDIR}/lora-gateway-bridge.toml ${D}/var/config/lora-gateway-bridge/lora-gateway-bridge.toml

    install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/lora-gateway-bridge.toml ${D}${LORA_GATEWAY_BRIDGE_DIR}/

    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/lora-gateway-bridge.init ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/lora-gateway-bridge
}

FILES_${PN} += "${LORA_GATEWAY_BRIDGE_DIR}"
FILES_${PN}-dbg += "${LORA_GATEWAY_BRIDGE_DIR}/.debug"


CONFFILES_${PN} += "/var/config/lora-gateway-bridge/lora-gateway-bridge.toml"
#CONFFILES_${PN} += "/etc/lora/lora-gateway-bridge.toml"
```

So I only changed the folder for the .toml file.
The part I really did change is the **.init Script**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DESC="LoRa Gateway Bridge"
NAME=lora-gateway-bridge
DAEMON=/opt/$NAME/$NAME
PID_FILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
OPT_CONF_DIR=/opt/$Name
CONFIG_DIR=/var/config/$NAME
CONFIG_FILE=/var/config/$NAME/$NAME.toml


function do_start {
    OPT_CONF_FILE=$OPT_CONF_DIR/lora-gateway-bridge.toml
    if ! [ -f $CONFIG_FILE ]; then
        echo "No Config-Files found, Copying ..."
        mkdir -p $CONFIG_DIR
        cp $OPT_CONF_FILE $CONFIG_FILE
    fi
    start-stop-daemon \
        --start \
        --background \
        --make-pidfile --pidfile "$PID_FILE" \
        --exec $DAEMON -- --config $CONFIG_FILE
}

function do_stop {
    start-stop-daemon \
        --stop \
        --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 \
        --pidfile "$PID_FILE" \
        --exec "$DAEMON"
    retval="$?"
    sleep 1
    return "$retval"
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting $DESC"
        do_start
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping $DESC"
        do_stop
        ;;
    restart)
        echo "Restarting $DESC"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
            0|1)
                do_start
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Sadly, in the init.d/lora-gateway-bridge file on the gateway, the script is always the old (unedited) one from the source.

I did change it, because the .toml file never got installed (I think because /var/vonfig is protected), so I first install it in the opt bin and then copy it on the first start.

I guess since I already build that recipe, yocto thinks it has already done its deed with it and doesn't rebuild the linux-image even if this module changed.

How can I fix this?

Every help is really appreciated!

Comment: are you sure package is part of the image?

Comment: Also, can you provide recipe sources or reference to layers?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk yes I did add it with IMAGE_INSTALL += (for reference: see the image recipe file, I edited it in)

Comment: @Nayfe yes sure, I put everything in the question, I didn't put it in from beginning because it is a lot and I thought it might be an easy fix.

Comment: did you try to add `inherit  update-rc.d`, `INITSCRIPT_NAME = "lora-gateway-bridge"`?  I would try to remove `PRIORITY` line, and also use `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p lora-gateway-bridge` to see if files are correctly included.

Comment: @Nayfe I would love to show you the output of the oe-pkgdata but I always get the error, that python 3.4 is required, but building the mlinux-image doesn't work beyond 3.x.